# Validate() function for multiple conditions in Shiny, Rstudio

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I have wrote a simplified version of my code so hopefully someone will be able to give me a direction to go in. I am trying to do a validate() process in shiny so that it will prevent my function SPC_macro from running if it fails. I know you can write multiple need clauses which can make the validate process fail independently but i need these clauses to be combined. example: below i have the validation clauses of mean=1, sigma=1, phase1=15, and userk=3.1. I am trying to get the validate function to only return a false sigma(which would stop my function from running) if theses values are all set together. so if the user was to input a mean=1, sigma=1, phase1=15 and a userk=3.8 the validate would pass and the function would run. I am also wondering if it is possible to make multiple failing combinations. I have run 3 simulations and these are the ones I am trying to prevent from being rerun by the user.

sim 1: mean=1, sigma=1, phase1=15, userk=3.1

sim 2: mean=2, sigma=2, phase1=30, userk=3.6

sim 3: mean=2, sigma=2, phase1=30, userk=4.0

```
`%then%` <- shiny:::`%OR%`
mean<-c(1,2,3)
sd<-c(1,2,3)
phase1<-c(15,20,25,30)
k<-(c(3,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$mean <- renderUI({
  selectInput('mean', 'Mean', mean)
})
output$sigma<-renderUI({

  selectInput('sigma',"variation",sd)
})
output$phase1<-renderUI({
  selectInput('phase1','phase1', phase1)
})
output$userk<-renderUI({
  selectInput('userk','userk',k)
})

rankuser<-eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
  validate(
    need(input$mean !="1","Data Already Exists")%then%
    need(input$sigma !="1", "data exists")%then%
    need(input$phase1!="15", "data extists")%then%
    need(input$userk != "3.1", "data already exists")
  )
  SPC_macro(nphase1=input$phase1, nphase2=100000, varcount=1, meanshift=input$mean, sigmashift=input$sigma, k=input$userK, simID=100)
  userdata<-rank_user_combined
})
})
```

edit: 
I tried what @nice suggested by doing:

```
rankuser<-eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
    data_calculated<-list(val_data)
     validate(
      need(any(sapply(data_calculated,
              function(x) identical(x,c(input$usernphase1,input$usermean,input$userSD,input$userk))),"Data Already Exists")
    )
    SPC_macro(nphase1=input$usernphase1, nphase2=100000, varcount=1, meanshift=input$usermean, sigmashift=input$userSD, k=input$userK, simID=100)
    userdata<-rank_user_combined
  })
```

the structure of what the data_calculated looks like(the list has about 400 rows total):

```
> data_calculated
[[1]]
    nphase1 meanshift sigmashift   k
1        10         4        1.0 3.0
2        15         0        1.0 3.0
3        15         0        1.0 3.1
4        15         0        1.0 3.2
5        15         0        1.0 3.3
6        15         0        1.0 3.4
7        15         0        1.0 3.5
8        15         0        1.0 3.6
9        15         0        1.0 3.7
10       15         0        1.0 3.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to make a list of all parameters for which you have calculated the data, for ex:

```
#make a list of vectors for which you have calculated values
data_calculated<-split(val_data,row.names(val_data))
data_calculated <- lapply(data_calculated,as.numeric)
```

When the user clicks go, you can check whether the parameters are in this list:

```
any(sapply(data_calculated,
           function(x) identical(x,c(input$mean,input$sigma,input$phase1,input$userk))
    )
    )
```

The `sapply` will loop through `data_calculated` and compare it to the vector made of the user inputs. `any` will return `TRUE` if an identical vector is found and false otherwise.

If you wrap it into the `need` it should validate the input.

Comment: I tried this method but it seems as those it is still testing the value of each variable rather than matching the values of each variable in the vector. I added an edit to the post about the method i did to implement it as well as a snap of the data_calculated list i used.

Comment: I edited the code, `data_calculated` needs to be a list of vectors for which you have calculated values. I assumed `val_data` was a data frame

Comment: The edits worked, I had tried to make my data.frame into a list by doing `data_calc<- list(val_data)` but apparently its not that simple. Thanks